# Removing subviews from a UITableViewCell with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`. Certain subviews in the cell are shown/removed depending on the properties of the object. I'm using auto layout and a xib. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (![some condition]) {
    [self.descriptionLabel setText:descText];
} else {
    [self.descriptionLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is a rough diagram of the cell

```
-----------------------------
    topLabel

    descriptionLabel

    bottomLabel
-----------------------------
```

The only label that may be removed is the description label. I have a constraint from the `bottomLabel` to `descriptionLabel` and another from `bottomLabel` to `topLabel` with a lower priority. When the `descriptionLabel` is removed, the `bottomLabel` correctly assumes to lower priority constraint.

The issue arises in what I assume is cell reuse, when I scroll up/down and a cell with the `descriptionLabel` has been removed is reused, it is not re-added.

#### Alternates I've tried:

- Hiding the `descriptionLabel` vs removing it, however, this way it maintains it's frame and hence the `bottomLabel` isn't moved up.

Will I have to re initialize the label and add it to the view? Or is there a better way to handling this use case?

Comment: this has  nothing to do with constraints

Comment: show us the code, when you are showing the hidden label back to the cell

Comment: once you hide a label, it is hidden forever unless you change it's hidden property again. where are you changing the hidden property?

Comment: one more thing, why do you want it to remove from superview when you can hide it?

Comment: @Mr.T By just hiding the label, it keeps its frame and therefore the bottomLabel doesn't move up.

Comment: Got it. When are you adding it back ?

Comment: @Mr.T, that's the part I'm stuck on. Since I'm using a xib, I'm not sure how to add it back while keeping the existing constraints set in the xib.

Comment: When you hide the descriptionLabel you should call layoutIfNeeded method after changing the constraints. While changing constraints, you should change their priorities. bottomLabel to topLabel constraint's priority should be high and bottomLabel to descriptionLabel constraint's priority should be low. This is better than removing and adding back the label. Did you tried this?

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren, you're right. It works! Thanks.

Comment: Please mark my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hide the `descriptionLabel` you should call `layoutIfNeeded` method after changing the constraints. While changing constraints, you should change their priorities. `bottomLabel` to `topLabel` constraint's priority should be high and `bottomLabel` to `descriptionLabel` constraint's priority should be low. This is better than removing and adding back the label.